# JMeter 3.3 __RandomDate with no parameters throws exception in Function Helper Dialog

Tags: jmeter

I use JMeter 3.3, I opened the Function Helper and tried the new function [__RandomDate](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomDate), Click Generate and got an error (other functions are working)

When calling in Test Plan `${__RandomDate(,2017-01-01,2018-01-01,,)}` it works, but in Function Helper when you click Generate it ignores the input field and use the function without any values

```
2017-09-25 08:44:30,112 ERROR o.a.j.f.RandomDate: Failed to parse the date '' to shift with formatter 'Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)'-'Value(MonthOfYear,2)'-'Value(DayOfMonth,2)java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$DefaultValueParser@6426866cjava.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$DefaultValueParser@4b46653bjava.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$DefaultValueParser@108462fd'
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.RandomDate.execute(RandomDate.java:189) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:137) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:112) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.gui.FunctionHelper.actionPerformed(FunctionHelper.java:181) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
2017-09-25 08:44:30,113 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be greater than origin
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.nextLong(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.RandomDate.execute(RandomDate.java:196) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:137) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:112) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.gui.FunctionHelper.actionPerformed(FunctionHelper.java:181) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
```

**EDIT**

Opened a [bug](http://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61561).

Comment: JMeter bug tracker is here: http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

Comment: opened a bug https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because "**End date**" is mandatory.

Since 3.3, **Generate** does an additional thing which is to show the result of function call.

But as you're not filling end date it fails with the error message you mention.

Fill in the required parameters and it works as documented:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomDate

As you can see **End date is required**

[image]

Comment: When click Generate it calls without any parameters (ignore input field), other functions with mandatory fields "works" or don't throws errors as ${__property(,,)}

Comment: It is just that other functions  fail silently when parameters are missing, typically __property is in this case